# Arduino IDE : 'tansig' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, c++

I am working on a simple NN sketch, everything looks fine and also i have added #include math.h .but when i try to compile it gives an error i-e **'tansig' is not defined in this scope**

I am trying to implement neural networks on obstacle avoiding robot.
Weights(Constants) are extracted from matlab training file.
How to make **tansig** work with arduino IDE

```
#include <math.h>
byte p1,p2,p3;
float n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,n11,n12,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8;

int Echo1 = A4; //LEFT_SENSOR ECHO
int Trig1 = A5; //LEFT_SENSOR TRIG
int Echo2 = A2; //MID_SENSOR ECHO
int Trig2 = A3; //MID_SENSOR TRIG
int Echo3 = A0; //RIGHT_SENSOR ECHO
int Trig3 = A1; //RIGHT_SENSOR TRIG

//Motor driver outputs

#define m11 3
#define m12 4
#define m21 5
#define m22 6

int Left_Distance = 0,Right_Distance = 0,Middle_Distance = 0 ;

/*Ultrasonic distance measurement Sub function*/
int Left_Distance_test() 
{
digitalWrite(Trig1, LOW); 
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(Trig1, HIGH); 
delayMicroseconds(20);
digitalWrite(Trig1, LOW); 
float Fdistance = pulseIn(Echo1, HIGH); 
delay(10);

Fdistance= Fdistance/ 29 / 2; 
return (int)Fdistance;
}

int Middle_Distance_test() 
{
digitalWrite(Trig2, LOW); 
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(Trig2, HIGH); 
delayMicroseconds(20);
digitalWrite(Trig2, LOW); 
float Fdistance = pulseIn(Echo2, HIGH);
delay(10);

Fdistance= Fdistance/ 29 / 2; 
return (int)Fdistance;
}

int Right_Distance_test() 
{
digitalWrite(Trig3, LOW); 
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(Trig3, HIGH); 
delayMicroseconds(20);
digitalWrite(Trig3, LOW); 
float Fdistance = pulseIn(Echo3, HIGH); 
delay(10);

Fdistance= Fdistance/ 29 / 2; 
return (int)Fdistance;
}


void setup() 
{

pinMode(Echo1, INPUT); 
pinMode(Trig1, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(Echo2, INPUT); 
pinMode(Trig2, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(Echo3, INPUT); 
pinMode(Trig3, OUTPUT); 

  pinMode(m11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m21, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m22, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() 
{
  Left_Distance = Left_Distance_test();
delay(10);
Middle_Distance = Middle_Distance_test();
delay(10);
Right_Distance = Right_Distance_test();
delay(10);

p1=Left_Distance;
p2=Middle_Distance;
p3=Right_Distance;

n1=(0.0588*p1)+(-2.7382*p2)+(-2.2898*p3)+(5.2586);
n2=(-3.1601*p1)+(-2.2137*p2)+(1.7397*p3)+(1.4386);
n3=(2.2931*p1)+(0.3145*p2)+(3.5053*p3)+(-1.0167);
s1=tansig(n1);
s2=tansig(n2);
s3=tansig(n3);

n4=(1.1021*s1)+(1.2825*s2)+(-1.9864*s3)+(-2.3891);
n5=(-0.5501*s1)+(1.8527*s2)+(-2.0468*s3)+(1.4314);
n6=(0.4322*s1)+(-0.2474*s2)+(-2.5017*s3)+(-0.5222);
n7=(-0.2658*s1)+(-2.0624*s2)+(-2.2511*s3)+(1.0958);
n8=(1.7401*s1)+(1.1111*s2)+(1.2254*s3)+(2.4701);
s4=tansig(n4);
s5=tansig(n5);
s6=tansig(n6);
s7=tansig(n7);
s8=tansig(n8);

n9=(1.0819*s4)+(-1.0897*s5)+(0.0658*s6)+(-0.1232*s7)+(0.3510*s8)+(1.2990);
n10=(-1.0865*s4)+(1.0899*s5)+(-0.062*s6)+(0.1241*s7)+(0.5818*s8)+(-0.7316);
n11=(-0.2292*s4)+(-0.0606*s5)+(1.0508*s6)+(-0.9711*s7)+(1.1635*s8)+(0.2269);
n12=(0.2262*s4)+(0.0607*s5)+(-1.0482*s6)+(0.9717*s7)+(-0.5215*s8)+(0.6312);


digitalWrite(m11,n9);
digitalWrite(m12,n10);
digitalWrite(m11,n11);
digitalWrite(m11,n12);


}
```

**error**: 'tansig' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Show the code and the error. We cannot guess.

Comment: Maybe we can guess -- `tansig` is not defined in `math.h` and `math.h` does not provide any functions for neural networks. Are you coding for an Arduino?

Comment: @josecanuc Code Added.

Comment: @jsotola Code Added and statement redefined

Comment: I'm re-opening this question because it seems clear enough. How to get the function **tansig** to compile?

Comment: @NickGammon Yeah i tried that, But output of tanh are not suitable to write for motor inputs. They are [ -0.xxx or 1.xxx  or 0.xxx].

Comment: If it is mathematically equivalent, wouldn't tansig be the same? **What** motor inputs? What numbers are you expecting? Can't you translate the range you are getting into the range needed by the motors?

Comment: @NickGammon that is what i wanted to ask,Motors get only HIGH or LOW or we can say 0,1. But i am getting range in negative and postive decimal numbers. How to translate those outputs to some other which suits motor driver

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: You have quite a lot of floating point math here, and the `tanh()` calls are going to be expensive. You will have to measure the speed of your program and make sure it is fast enough for the application. If not, you may have to replace `tanh()` by a cheaper alternative, or go fixed-point, or get a more capable processor.

Answer (score -1):

According to: http://au.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/tansig.html

> **Algorithms**
>
> ```
> a = tansig(n) = 2/(1+exp(-2*n))-1
> ```
>
> This is mathematically equivalent to tanh(N).

So, replace calls to `tansig` by `tanh`. Or, make a define to do it:

```
#define tansig(n) tanh(n)
```

---

> But output of tanh are not suitable to write for motor inputs. They are [ -0.xxx or 1.xxx or 0.xxx].

...

> How to translate those outputs to some other which suits motor driver

There is a [map function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) in the IDE which lets you translate from one range to another.

---

> map() works only on long integers (comment by Edgar Bonet)

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

OK, well write your own function that does the same thing to floats. Example:

```
float fmap(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

Comment: `map()` works only on long integers.

Comment: See amended answer.